# How to Save bitmap to app folder in android

Tags: java, android, android-file

I have a bitmap that I want to save it to the app folder. I try with these codes:

```
 ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(context.getApplicationContext());
 File directory = contextWrapper.getDir("tabs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 if (!directory.exists())
     directory.mkdir();
     String fname = "Image.jpg";
     File file = new File(directory, fname);
     FileOutputStream fos = null;
     try {
         fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
         bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, fos);
         fos.close();
     } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SAVE_IMAGE", e.getMessage(), e);
     }
```

Now, I have two problems.

1. Why this warning show and how to fix it?

> Result of 'File.mkdir()' is ignored

2. Directory "app_tabs" was created in the application folder, But not saved bitmap and There is no photo in the folder. How do I save this bitmap?

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: Better: `if (!directory.exists())
     if (!directory.mkdir()){toast could not make directory... return;}`.

Comment: `Why this warning show ` ? Which warning?

Comment: @blackapps **Result of 'File.mkdir()' is ignored**

Comment: How do you check if the file is there?

Comment: Is ignored? Why would you?  Ignored means badly written code.

Comment: @blackapps I added a picture in the post.

Comment: did you add the permission ?

Comment: @MuhamedEl-Banna in the manifest, I added _READ-EXTERNAL-STORAGE_ and _WRITE-EXTERNAL-STORAGE_ permission.

Comment: \\ i will post my answer for how to create directory .. try it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
try {
     FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = context.openFileOutput("Your File Name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
     bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOutputStream);
     fileOutputStream.close();
 } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

It saves your bitmap in the "files" directory in app folder.

Comment: Thank you! Its work and saved my image. But, How to save it in another folder?

Comment: I checked your codes and I think are correct. As fujian26 said, You need to click the 'Synchronize' menu.

Comment: what is the path of saved Bitmap? How to get that?

Answer (score 1):

```
 String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString() + "/tabs";
        File dir = new File(path);
        if (!dir.exists())
            dir.mkdirs();

        File futureStudioIconFile = new File(path, "Image.jpg);
        if (futureStudioIconFile.exists())
            futureStudioIconFile.delete();
        futureStudioIconFile.createNewFile();
```

try this ,, i wish it helps

Comment: Thank you for your time, but I want to save my bitmap in the app folder directory, Not in the download folder. And my problem isn't to create a directory, I was able to create a directory. I cant save bitmap in the folder created in root files(app folder).

Comment: \\ you are most welcome .. am still trying to get an answer..... you are using **context** to **getApplicationContext** .. why ? ,, i think you have to remove **context** and try again

Comment: \\ contextWrapper.getDir() creates the folder if it doesn't exist, so calling mkdir() is redundant .. so **Result of 'File.mkdir()' is ignored**

Answer (score 1):

Technically your codes is correct, also I had tried on my own device all is correct.

So I suspect you find the other path, or you need to click 'Synchronize' menu if you use Android Studio to check file.

By the way, you can just use context or context.getApplicationContext() to call getDir(), no need to new a ContextWrapper. like this:

```
File directory = context.getDir("tabs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my answer

1. `Result of 'File.mkdir()' is ignored` : Because mkdir() return a boolean, `true` if the folder is created and false otherwwise.
2. This is how I save bitmap

```
        File storageDir = getFilesDir();

        File filePath = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );


        try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath)) {
            capturedImg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, out);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

or if you just want to save the bitmap at original resolution

```
    public static void copy(Uri uri, File dst, Context context) {
        try (InputStream in = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
             OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst)) {
            // Transfer bytes from in to out
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```